# Rewrite all http traffic to https with a couple exceptions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite all pages and assets to https, with exceptions for a couple specific pages. Here's my current htaccess code, which works fine for the broad https rewrite. I just need to figure out how to add page-specific exceptions to this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

The pages I want to exclude are as follows:

- cron.php
- mailer_confirmjob.php
- mailer_followup.php
- cron_duplicate_check.php
- mailer_periodicfollowup.php

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^((?!(cron|mailer_confirmjob|mailer_followup|cron_duplicate_check|mailer_periodicfollowup)\.php).*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]
```